# php file_put_contents takes 2sec and is not blocking

Tags: php, sed, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I'm currently doing a config.inc file

```
<?php echo 'old value';
```

that I edit with preg_replace and file_put_content :

```
include("config.inc");//this shows me the old value
$txt = file_get_contents("config.inc");//but this show the new value

if ($_GET['val']) {
    file_put_contents("config.inc", "<?php echo '".$_GET['val']."';");
    //echo "content now is".file_get_contents("config.inc");
    //hey ! i changed your value says file_get_content()

    //sleep(5);//this currently solve the issue, but that's not a solution
    header('Location: /adminprivate/testing.php');
    exit();
}
else {
    echo htmlspecialchars($txt);
    echo "
    <form method='get'>
        <input type='text' name='val' />
        <button type='submit'>Change value</button>
    </form>";
}
```

my problem is that my include() echoes the old value for about two seconds after the file_put_content() call, but is non blocking as my page reload.

right now, and even if I use `exec('sed -i ...')`, php don't seem to wait for the file to be written, and just reload too early.

the problem is not with the header, as if i reload manually within 2 seconds, the old value is there.

---

I want to know why file_get_content can find the right content when include find the old one, and how to prevent my page from reloading unless i'm 100% sure my include will work

Comment: This doesn't look like a good idea to begin with. What are you trying to do with this? Why don't you just write the variable contents to the file and `echo file_get_contents` instead?

Comment: this changes my config.inc file, wich contain variables declarations, not echos ;) like `<?php $list_modifs = array(...);`

Comment: That sounds like a bad strategy. You can store your configuration parameters in a JSON file and read/write to that instead. It's not a good idea to dynamically modify code. Also are you running opcache?

Comment: putting a value in a file that will be rewritten later is a bad idea, try using a db it will be easier and away faster

Comment: i actually can't use a db only for that, and you could see that as an unserialize, serialize kind of file, but it's actually implemented with an include, that performs a lot of test and was modified by hand.
I know this is not the best way, but this is what I was given to work with